# is.null does not work on null data.table in R [possible bug]?

Tags: r, data.table

I believe this might be a bug. If so, I will report. Looking for confirm:

```
> is.null(data.table(NULL))
  [1] FALSE
```

I see the following in FAQ:

> 2.5 Is a NULL data.table the same as DT[0]?
>   No, despite the print method indicating otherwise. Strictly speaking it's not possible to have
>   is.null(data.table(NULL)) return FALSE. This FAQ may be revisited in future.

If this is the intended behavior: how does one check if the object is null? In particular, `rbindlist` of a NULL object returns a `NULL data.table` so how to check?

```
> is.null(rbindlist(NULL))
  [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why the FAQ is phrased the way it is.  However, a null data table is just an empty list:

```
> data.table:::null.data.table
function () 
{
    ans = list()
    setattr(ans, "class", c("data.table", "data.frame"))
    setattr(ans, "row.names", .set_row_names(0L))
    settruelength(ans, 0L)
    alloc.col(ans)
}
```

which isn't `NULL`.  From `?list`:

> An empty pairlist, pairlist() is the same as NULL. This is different
>   from list().

You could check for it by seeing whether it is of length 0 (`length(DT) == 0`).  This is what `data.table:::print.data.table` does to decide whether to print "NULL data.table" or "Empty data table (0 rows) ...".

Comment: thanks! that's what i ended up doing.. jsut checked if `nrow(DT)==0`

Comment: @Alex length(DT)==0 is the same as ncol(DT)==0 not nrow(DT)==0.

Comment: The FAQ is trying to say that is.null(data.frame(NULL)) is FALSE too and since is.null isn't S3 generic we can't change that for data.table even if we wanted to.  The only thing that's NULL is NULL.

Comment: Hm. `data.table(NULL)` printing "NULL data.table" seem to be the problem, that's misleading isn't it. The `data.frame(NULL)` output of `data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows` seems better.

Answer (score 5):

Good point. Have now changed the output of `data.table(NULL)`. From NEWS in v1.8.9 :

> - `data.table(NULL)` now prints `"Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)"` and FAQ 2.5 has been improved. Thanks to : [is.null does not work on null data.table in R [possible bug]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317536/is-null-does-not-work-on-null-data-table-in-r-possible-bug)

FAQ 2.5 now reads :

> FAQ 2.5 *Is a null data.table the same as DT[0]?*
>  No. By ”null data.table” we mean the result of `data.table(NULL)` or `as.data.table(NULL)`; i.e.,

```
> data.table(NULL)
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
> as.data.table(NULL)
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
> data.frame(NULL)
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
> as.data.frame(NULL)
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

> The null `data.table|frame` is `NULL` with some attributes attached, making it not
>   `NULL` anymore. In R only pure `NULL` is `NULL` as tested by `is.null()`. When
>   referring to the ”null data.table” we use lower case null to help
>   distinguish from upper case NULL. To test for the null data.table, use
>   `length(DT)==0` or `ncol(DT)==0` (`length` is slightly faster as it’s a
>   primitive function). An empty data.table (`DT[0]`) has one or more
>   columns, all of which are empty. Those empty columns still have names
>   and types :

```
> DT = data.table(a=1:3,b=c(4,5,6),d=c(7L,8L,9L))
> DT[0]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: a,b,d
> sapply(DT[0],class) 
        a         b         d 
"integer" "numeric" "integer"
```